# Positioning elements in <a>

Tags: html, css

I use CSS Grid in my website. In grids, I've got photos with description (made with figcaption) and everything is inside  markup. Now I'd like to display in the middle of grid cell with description below the photo. Now in properties of grid cell I've got

```
 justify-items: center;
 align-items : center;
 display: flex;
```

But description is still to the right of the image.
How can I display dscription below?

My HTML

```
 <a  href="computer.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($computer['IdC']);?>">  
 <img alt="" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($computer['img11']); ?>" >

 <div class="caption">             
<figcaption> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($computer['Name']);  ?></figcaption>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: use `flex-direction: column` to wrap next element

Answer (score 0):

use flex-direction: column to wrap next element